# how Inner join work on two foreign key from single table

Tags: sql

I am working on Bus route management system , I made two table first one is Cities and second one is route have following queries

```
CREATE TABLE Cities 
    ( 
      ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) PRIMARY KEY,
      Name Varchar(30) not null,
)
CREATE TABLE route
    ( 
      ID NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(START with 1 INCREMENT by 1) PRIMARY KEY,
      Name Varchar(30) not null,
      from NUMBER not null,
      to NUMBER NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT FROM_id_FK FOREIGN KEY(from) REFERENCES Cities(ID),
      CONSTRAINT TO_id_FK FOREIGN KEY(to) REFERENCES Cities(ID),
)
```

i am joining the table through inner join

```
select CITIES.Name  
from CITIES
inner join ROUTES on CITIES.ID=ROUTES.ID
```

but it show single column as

```
   Name                        
-----------
```

but i want result as

```
    from  |     to     
------------------------
```

what is possible way to do this using inner join

Comment: You need to select from `Routes` and join `Cities` for each `from` and `to`. Also note that "from" and "to" are poor choices for column names, probably "source" and "destination" might be better.

Comment: I will update the table source to destination

Comment: can you write code for me ?

Comment: This might be helpful to you. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-joins/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need something like the following:

```
select r.Name, cs.Name SourceCity, cd.Name DestinationCity
from routes r
join cities cs on cs.id = r.from
join cities cd on cd.id = r.to
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope is working for you

```
select CITIES.Name,ROUTES.from,ROUTES.to 
from CITIES inner join ROUTES on CITIES.ID=ROUTES.ID
```